# Reference the controls of a subform from a global function

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to run the below global function. I am basically passing it the name of the form and cycling through the controls to get the before and after values. This has been working fine up until I wanted to capture the values from a sub form. I recently added the `Optional tempParentFormName As String` parameter. Now I am trying to get the syntax right for the controls of the sub form. `Forms(tempParentFormName).Form(funFormName).Controls` is not working. **What should it be?** The version for a from without a sub (`Forms(funFormName).Controls`) works fine.

```
Public Function funDeleteGetFieldValues(funFormName As String, 
                                        tempFieldsValues1 As String, 
                                        tempFieldsValues2 As String, 
                                        Optional tempParentFormName As String)
    Dim ctl As Control, tempProperControl As Boolean, tempCounter As Integer
    tempCounter = 1
    tempFieldsValues1 = ""
    tempFieldsValues2 = ""
    
    For Each ctl In Forms(tempParentFormName).Form(funFormName).Controls
        'A bunch of code
    Next ctl
    Set ctl = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the *subform* control to use:

```
Forms(tempParentFormName)(subformControlName).Form.Controls
```

Comment: Thanks, I new it was something simple and I was just getting hung up on it. Your answer worked.

Comment: After trying a bunch of stuff I just figured out that `Forms(tempParentFormName).Controls(funFormName).Controls` works as well.